# Create a pop up textbox that shows the cell data

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

Just a disclaimer, I know absolutely nothing about VBA, the code below is one I've found googling.
But I still can't get it to work consistently. I just want a popup to appear when clicking on a cell that shows all the text in the cell. The reason for this is that I want fixed width on rows, which means not all text is visible that way.

````
 On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A65000")) Is Nothing Then
 UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = Target.Value
 UserForm1.Show
End If
End Sub```
````

Comment: Since you only want fixed width, can't you wrap text? You should remove `On Error Resume Next` as it is hiding potential errors from you. If there is error, please provide details of the error (error code, description etc). It seems like you want to show text in the cell if it is in column A, perhaps you can simplify your condition to `If Target.Column = 1 Then`

Comment: Using wrap text still means you end up cell of unequal size. As for the error, when I run the code, the textbox appears (albeit empty). But when I click on any cell in the specified range, nothing happens. Ideally I want to show text in specific columns only

Comment: Is the userform Modeless? Check for the `ShowModal` property in the Userform or change this line `UserForm1.Show` to `UserForm1.Show False`

Comment: `ShowModal` is set to True

Comment: Try changing it to `False`, if `ShowModal` is `True` then you can only interact with the Userform until you close it, setting it to `False` allows you to interact with the worksheet while the Userform is opened.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. But on the few occasions when it did work, I didn't have to do any changes to the userform properties, I just changed `MultiLine` to `True`

Comment: In that case, you have to provide more examples of your code, screenshot of the cells (especially those that didn't work consistently) if you need more help. Otherwise we are just throwing guesses at it.

Comment: I'm a moron, I entered the code in the wrong place. Should be in the sheet code. Thanks Raymond for your help :)

Comment: Good to know that it worked out!